# R Joining two datasets with same rowcount and index columns

Tags: r, join, merge, left-join, dplyr

I have two datasets dataset1

```
 Id   A    B
 1    Y    N
 2    N    N
 3    Na   Na
 4    Y    Y
```

dataset 2

```
 Id   A    C
 1    Y    Y
 2    N    Y
 3    Na   N
 4    Y    N
```

I am trying to join these two datasets based on their ID column and produce a dataset like this

```
 Id   A    B    C
 1    Y    N    Y
 2    N    N    Y
 3    Na   Na   N
 4    Y    Y    N
```

When i try left_join(dataset1, datase2, by="ID") i get more rows than one should expect, like this

```
 Id   A    B    C
 1    Y    N    Y
 2    N    N    Y
 2         N    
 3    Na   Na   N
 3              N
 4    Y    Y    N
```

When I do a merge, merge(dataset1, dataset2) its the opposite I get less number of rows , can somebody tell me where I am going wrong, sorry this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Both `merge` and `dplyr::left_join` give me the same results. I don't know how you are getting the result you are.

Comment: The column is "Id" not "ID".  Is this: `left_join(dataset1, dataset2, by=c("Id","A"))` what you want?

Comment: @thelatemail, I agree with you. I had merge and dplyr::left_joing working fine before in other instances, now I am seeing some erratic results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my trial.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id = 1:4,
                  A = c("Y","N",NA,"Y"),
                  B = c("N","N",NA,"Y"))
df2 <- data.frame(Id = 1:4,
                  A = c("Y","N",NA,"Y"),
                  C = c("Y","Y","N","N"))
merge(df1, df2, by="Id")
  Id  A.x    B  A.y C
1  1    Y    N    Y Y
2  2    N    N    N Y
3  3 <NA> <NA> <NA> N
4  4    Y    Y    Y N
```

You may retry from `left_join(dataset1, datase2, by="ID")` to  `left_join(dataset1, datase2, by="Id")`.

Comment: I figured where I went wrong I had mangled the column names in the previous step. I fixed that and everything fell in place. +10 for trying :)